# Complete positivity vs Positivity.

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, operator-theory, hilbert-spaces, operator-algebras

It is easy to see that an orthogonal projection on a separable Hilbert space is positive.

A completely positive map $T$ is one for which every tensor product

$$T\otimes \operatorname{id}_{\mathbb C^{n \times n}}$$ is still positive.

Thus I was wondering whether this is true for an orthogonal projection as well?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks to me that you are confusing two things. A projection $p$ on $H$ is positive as an element of $B(H)$, since $p=p^*p$. It is positive in the sense that it is selfadjoint and its spectrum is nonnegative.

But when you discuss complete positivity of a map $T$, you need $T$ to positive *as a map* (i.e., in the sense that it maps positive elements to positive elements). So the domain of $T$ is a C$^*$-algebra, or more generally an operator system.  Such notion makes no sense for an orthogonal projection, since you have no positivity in the Hilbert space.